# MySQL / PHP: how to display only one category with related items

Tags: php, mysql

My goal is to select all items related to a specific category from a database with PHP and MySQL.
Using the script below I can select all categories with the related items.

```
$sql = query("SELECT bike AS 'cat_name', c.image AS 'image', p.title AS    'product_name'
                FROM products p
                INNER JOIN categories c
                ON p.category_id = c.id");

while( $row = mysqli_fetch_array($sql)) {
echo $row['cat_name'].'<br />';
echo $row['product_name'].'<br />';
echo $row['image'];
}
```

This is the result:

**Bike**
item 1
item 2
item 3
...

**Bike**
item 1
item 2
item 3
...

The result above does not reflect the desired result.
I would like to have only one Category selected with the related items like this:

**Bike**
item 1
item 2
item 3
...

Comment: You need to use `Group_concat`

Comment: try running your query in the msql console and see the result

Comment: I used following script: "SELECT bike AS 'cat_name', c.image AS 'image', GROUP_CONCAT(p.title)AS 'product_name' 
                    FROM products p 
                    INNER JOIN categories c 
                    ON p.category_id = c.id 
                    GROUP BY p.category_id"

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$sql = query("SELECT bike AS 'c.cat_name', c.image AS 'image', p.title AS 'product_name'
FROM products p, categories c
WHERE p.categroy_id = c.id
AND p.id = THE_ID_OF_THE_CATEGORY ");
```